# Moodle 3.4 User creation error 'dmlwriteexception'

Tags: mysql, function, moodle

We have migrated our moodle website from inmotion hosting to new cPanel/WHM installed on EC2. Our database version is Mariadb 10.2 , PHP 7.2 (same as before). But while creating new user the database couldn't be written getting `dmlwriteexception` error:

```
Debug info: FUNCTION db.CAP_FIRST does not exist

INSERT INTO mdl_user (username,auth,suspended,firstname,lastname,email,maildisplay,city,country,timezone,theme,imagealt,firstnamephonetic,lastnamephonetic,middlename,alternatename,url,icq,skype,aim,yahoo,msn,idnumber,institution,department,phone1,phone2,address,timemodified,description,descriptionformat,mnethostid,confirmed,timecreated,password,calendartype,mailformat,maildigest,autosubscribe,trackforums,lang) VALUES(
)

Error code: dmlwriteexception

Stack trace:

    line 489 of /lib/dml/moodle_database.php: dml_write_exception thrown
    line 1300 of /lib/dml/mysqli_native_moodle_database.php: call to moodle_database->query_end()
    line 1346 of /lib/dml/mysqli_native_moodle_database.php: call to mysqli_native_moodle_database->insert_record_raw()
    line 107 of /user/lib.php: call to mysqli_native_moodle_database->insert_record()
    line 188 of /user/editadvanced.php: call to user_create_user()
```

Anyone had this issue before?

Comment: Moodle 3.4 isnt supported anymore. upgrade to moodle 3.10 or 3.9 if possible

Answer (score 0):

This is an usual issue when upgrading a moodle site, change dbcollation to **'utf8_general_ci'**